# Excel based tracking database

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which Sheet "RAW" is updated each day with more rows and updates the existing rows, I'm trying to get the number in Column B to match Column A in sheet data, then depending on what information is in other columns add 1 to a value in a column (17 different options)
It's basically going to be used as a tracker to check how many days something is on a specific status and I need to keep it for historical Measuring indefintely. here is what I have so far which doesn't seem to work.
Additionally I would also like it to measure an 18th catagory if it is missing from the data list if this is possibble?

```
'status tracking
Sub Status_Track()
    Dim a As Long 'topic number
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim S As Long
    Dim D As Long

    Worksheets("RAW").Activate
    R = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    C = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Z = 0
    i = 2
    Do Until i > R

        'ident
        If Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) And (Cells(i, 13) = "ERKA") Then
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 6) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 6).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) And (Cells(i, 13) = "INBA") Then
            'Inba
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 7) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 7).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) And (Cells(i, 13) = "ABGE") Then
            'Abge
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) And (Cells(i, 13) = "GELO") Then
            'Gelo
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) And (Cells(i, 13) = "UEBE") And (Cells(i, 11) = 0) Then
            'UEBE
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "<1") Then
            '1
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 10) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "6") Then
            '6
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 11) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 11).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "9") Then
            '9
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 12) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 12).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "10") Then
            '10
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 13) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 13).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "15") Then
            '15
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 14) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 14).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "30") Then
            '30
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 15) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 15).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "50") Then
            '50
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 16) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 16).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "60") Then
            '60
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 17) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 17).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "70") Then
            '70
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 18) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "80") Then
            '80
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 19) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 19).Value = Z
         ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "90") Then
            '90
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 20) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "97") Then
            '97
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 21) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 21).Value = Z
        ElseIf Cells(i, 11) = 1 And (Cells(i, 28) = "100") Then
            '100
            Z = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 22) + 1
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 22).Value = Z      
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Not the solution: But you should have a look into the [`ElseIf` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/752y8abs.aspx#Anchor_5) which makes your code a lot more readable and removes you all these `End If`s except of one! You only need one level of indentation then instead of 19 level. Better readable code results in less issues!

Comment: Thank you :)
I'll make that amendment :)

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" In what way does the behaviour of the code deviate from the desired behaviour? Or is there an error message? If so: what error message and on what line?

Comment: just another thing that should be corrected is: Variables that handle row/column counts or similar (in your code `R`, `C`, `i` , etc) need to be of the type `Long` not `Integer` because `Integer` is too small for the maximum row count.

Comment: I get a runtime error 6 "Overflow", it also stops on the first topic on the list and input 32767 instead of 1 (the cell was Empty beforehand).

Comment: @JonathonRolls-Drew the Overflow error is due to that `Integer` is limited to `32767` you need to use `Long` for row/column counting. See my comment above. Correct your code and update/edit it within your question too!

Comment: @Peh, please see updated code, the error and input is still the same. It seems like it's putting the information in the right column, but it gives the runtime error and still leaves the 32767 each time.

Comment: `i` is not incrementing inside your loop. Use `For i = 2 to R` and `Next i` instead of the `Do Until i > R` and `Loop`

Comment: It also might be a good idea to follow the [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201704060943470120326)-Guide. It's really worth the time reading it and follow it rules.

Comment: @Peh Thank you very much :) It seems to be working now. 
Currently they have to be in the same order from sheet to sheet, how would you get it to find the correct value and then input it in its corresponding place? Or is that a completely seperate code that I should start from scratch?

Comment: Which columns need to match if you say "to find the correct value"? Is it that column B of sheet Raw has to match column A of sheet Data?

Comment: @Peh Correct, So for example:
Sheet"Data" A2 find in Raw B:B, then depending on the criteria it allocated the count in the correct column in sheet "Data".
I've just realised how i've written it now means the Numbers in each row have to correspond between the sheets for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It could look something like that to find the corresponding identifier

```
Option Explicit 'must be the first line in a module: forces you to declare any variables before use

'status tracking
Sub Status_Track_Extended()
    Dim wsRaw As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsRaw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wsRaw.Cells(wsRaw.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row   'find last row in sheet RAW

    Dim FoundCell As Range, FoundRow As Long
    Dim DataCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRow   'start at row 2 up to last used row

        'find corresponding row by identifier (column 2) in sheet Data
        Set FoundCell = wsData.Columns(1).Find(wsRaw.Cells(i, 2))
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then 'only do the follwing if the identifier was found in sheet Data
            FoundRow = FoundCell.Row

            'ident
            If wsRaw.Cells(i, 13) = "ERKA" Then
                wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 6).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 6).Value + 1
            ElseIf wsRaw.Cells(i, 13) = "INBA" Then
                'Inba
                wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 7).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 7).Value + 1
            ElseIf wsRaw.Cells(i, 13) = "ABGE" Then
                'Abge
                wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 8).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 8).Value + 1
            ElseIf wsRaw.Cells(i, 13) = "GELO" Then
                'Gelo
                wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 5).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 5).Value + 1
            ElseIf wsRaw.Cells(i, 13) = "UEBE" And wsRaw.Cells(i, 11) = 0 Then
                'UEBE
                wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 9).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 9).Value + 1
            ElseIf wsRaw.Cells(i, 11) = 1 Then
                Select Case wsRaw.Cells(i, 28)
                    Case "<1"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 10).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 10).Value + 1
                    Case "6"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 11).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 11).Value + 1
                    Case "9"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 12).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 12).Value + 1
                    Case "10"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 13).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 13).Value + 1
                    Case "15"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 14).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 14).Value + 1
                    Case "30"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 15).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 15).Value + 1
                    Case "50"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 16).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 16).Value + 1
                    Case "60"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 17).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 17).Value + 1
                    Case "70"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 18).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 18).Value + 1
                    Case "80"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 19).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 19).Value + 1
                    Case "90"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 20).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 20).Value + 1
                    Case "97"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 21).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 21).Value + 1
                    Case "100"
                        wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 22).Value = wsData.Cells(FoundRow, 22).Value + 1
                End Select
            End If

        Else 'error if identifier was not found
            MsgBox "Identifier '" & wsRaw.Cells(i, 2) & "' could not be found in sheet 'Data'.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out :)